# Compare value in custom fields of multiple user picker

Tags: jira

I am new to groovy.
I'm trying to compare the value of two user multiple choice fields. as a result, if there is a match, display an error on the screen. for fields with one choice there are no problems. script

`def fieldA = getFieldByName('User Picker A')`

`if(fieldA.value == fieldB.valuee`
`def fieldB = getFieldByName('User Picker B')`
`def currentField = getFieldById(fieldChanged)`
`fieldA.clearError()`
`fieldB.clearError()`

```
{currentField.setError("Please select a different user. $currentField.value was already used.")}
```

for multiple selection I need to apply contains but I don't understand how to do it. stuck on it

// If the first option is selected in the multi select list then make the text field required.

```
if(selectVal1.contains("") ) {
```

currentField.setError( "Пожалуйста, выберите другого пользователя. Значение $currentField. уже было использовано." )
}`

Here thus I try to compare on matches of a field of a multiple choice of users. but i lack skills

```
SelectList1.getValue().each {
if(selectVal2.contains(selectVal1)) {
 currentField.setError( "Пожалуйста, выберите другого пользователя. Значение $currentField. уже было использовано." )}
}
```

I will be grateful for any help

Answer (score 0):

I hope someone will be useful. working code for comparing two given arrays, searching for matches and displaying an error

```
SelectList3.getValue().each {
if(selectVal3.contains("fokinanv") && (selectVal1.contains("fokinanv"))) {
 currentField.setError( "Пожалуйста, выберите другого пользователя. Значение $currentField. уже было использовано." )}

if(selectVal3.contains("zverevaav1") && (selectVal1.contains("zverevaav1"))) {
 currentField.setError( "Пожалуйста, выберите другого пользователя. Значение $currentField. уже было использовано." )}
```

и тд перебор условий